# select items in kendo list view via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a kendo list view to display candidate information, I need to select candidate items in the list view on data bound event based on a Boolean property "IsPerfectMatch" in the data item. The code is as below:

```
function onDataBound(){
var lisView = this;
$.each($("#dupCheckList").data("kendoListView").dataSource.data(),
          function(index, item){
                      if(item.IsPerfectMatch){
                          listView.select(this);
                       }
        });
}
```

When I debugged, I can see things working until the if block that checks "item.IsPerfectMatch" but the line of code "listView.select(this);" is not selecting the list item.

Please suggest where could I be going wrong.

Also, I have set the list view selection mode to multiple for this list view. I would want to disallow selection of only the first item in the list. In other words, apart from the first item in the list view, all other items are selectable. Please suggest with sample jQuery code on how to achieve  it.

Thanks and regards,
Damodar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView items are **NOT** the DataSource entries, so the value you're sending to the `select()` method is invalid.  To iterate over the viewable children you will have to use the `element.children()` call.

```
var listView = this;
$.each(this.element.children(), function(index, item) {
    if (listView.dataSource.getByUid(item.dataset.uid).IsPerfectMatch) {
        listView.select(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh Bramlett, this works with a minor change as below:
var listView = $("#dupCheckList").data("kendoListView");
 $.each(this.element.children(), function (index, item) {
         if (listView.dataSource.data()[index].IsPerfectMatch) {
             listView.select(item);
         }
     });

Comment: Hi Josh, I have a similar requirement. I need to highlight the specific child of a specific children based on condition in javascript. I have raised this as a separate quiestion "How can I highlight the specific item in a Kendo UI ListView?". Is it possible for you to look into it and answer if possible?